# How do I prove that $\cosh A + \cosh B = 2\cosh \frac{A+B}{2} \cosh \frac{A-B}{2}$ using only the definition of $\cosh x = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$?

Tags: proof-writing, hyperbolic-functions

How do I prove that $\cosh A + \cosh B = 2\cosh \frac{A+B}{2} \cosh \frac{A-B}{2}$ using only the definition of $\cosh x = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$?

After starting from the RHS, I got down to:

$\cosh A + \cosh B = e^{\frac{A^2-B^2}{4}} + e^{\frac{-(A^2-B^2)}{4}}$

Can anyone give me a hint on how to continue?

Comment: change the variables to $\frac{A+B}{2}=x,\,\frac{A-B}{2}=y$ and simplify the LHS instead. $\sinh(x) \sinh(y) \pm \cosh(x) \cosh(y)= \cosh(x\pm y)$ will be also needed, but can be easily derived from the definition.

Comment: Why don't you start from the addition formulæ for $\cosh$, just like one does for $\cos$?

Comment: Your expression with $A^2-B^2$ is not correct; to multiply terms you will need to use that $e^xe^y=e^{x+y}$

Comment: Yeah, I was aware that the addition formula might be required, which is why I specified from the definition only (simply because my teacher has not formally introduced the addition formula yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R.H.S should instead be $$\frac{(e^{\frac{A+B}{2}} +e^{\frac{-A-B}{2}} )(e^{\frac{A-B}{2}}+e^{\frac{B-A}{2}})}{2} =\frac{e^A+e^B +e^{-A} +e^{-B}}{2} \\ = \frac{e^A+e^{-A}}{2} + \frac{e^B + e^{-B}}{2}\\ =\cosh A + \cosh B$$

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple  and start from the factorisation formula
$$\cosh(u+v)+\cosh(u-v)=2\cosh u\cosh v,$$
readily deduced from the addition formulæ 
$$\cos(u\pm v)=\cosh u\cosh v\pm\sinh u\sinh, v$$
and solve the linear system
\begin{cases}
u+v=A, \\u-v=B.
\end{cases}